# Erro ao colocar lista no Android

Tags: java, android, xml

Estou começando agora com o desenvolvimento para Android. Tentei montar uma lista, porém não está dando certo. No Preview só aparece `Item 1, Subitem 1`.

Segue o .Java

```
public class Lista extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_lista);


    String[] alunos = {"Ygor", "Carlos", "Paulo", "Joao", "Pedro"}; //Defini o vetor com os nomes
    ListView lista_alunos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista); //(ListView) serve para converter a referência para ListView
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, alunos); //Transformar o Array para View
    lista_alunos.setAdapter(adapter); //Aqui a lista vai pedir para o adapter realizar a conversão para View
    }
}
```

e o .xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lista"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Alguém poderia ver o que está errado nesse código? Não consegui entender onde está o erro.

Comment: Qual sua dúvida? Isso ai deve funcionar sim mostrando todos os itens em formato de lista. Pelo que vejo não existe subitem.

Comment: No meu "Preview" do AndroidStudio, só está aparecendo "Item 1, Sub Item1, Item2, Sub Item2 ", a minha dúvida é por que não está aparecendo a String?

Comment: No preview nunca vai aparecer mesmo. Você precisa compilar seu projeto para que isso funcione.

Comment: Antes estavam aparecendo os nomes quando eu colocava todos os nomes em "TextView", vou testar aqui.

Comment: No text view aparece mesmo, mas tudo que você colocar dentro de sua classe, só aparecerá se você compilar.

Comment: Fui no simulador do Android e está aparecendo "process system isn't responding". Sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Não sei não. Você poderia editar sua pergunta e em vez de colocar "simulador" coloque o que é no "Preview" seu teste.

Answer (score 0):

No ***Preview*** do Android Studio, somente é possível ver o que estiver definido no XML. Para que você veja o que está definido na sua classe `Lista`, no qual é gerado uma lista usando `ListView`, é necessário compilar o projeto e executa-lo em uma maquina virtual(AVD) ou até mesmo no próprio *smartphone*.

Testei seu código e está funcionando perfeitamente, listando todos os itens declarados na variável `alunos`.